# Arguments are not being passed in directive function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Code

```
<div scope-isolation reversename="reverseNameFn()"></div>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.reverseNameFn = function(message){
     console.log(message);  //undefined
     return message;
  }
});

app.directive('scopeIsolation', function() {
  return{
    scope : {
       'reversename' : '&'
    },
    template : '<input type="text" ng-model="value"> {{value}} <button ng-click="reversename({message : value})">click me</button>',
    link : function(scope,elem,attrs){      
         console.log("Inside scope isolation directive");
    }
  }
});
```

When reversename({message : value}) is called the message object is undefined in the function.

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/c2hch5Kozr9yjRLWN6K9?p=preview

Comment: @BhojendraNepal That's in the HTML, he binds it correctly with the attribute name, so that's fine.

Comment: @OmriAharon Oh! I didn't see.

Comment: You call the function without any argument, so what should be passed?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with `&`, your expression gets evaluated. Your expression passed is `reverseNameFn()`.

If you want dynamically to pass variables, bind with `=`:

```
'reversename' : '='
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div scope-isolation reversename="reverseNameFn"></div>
```

Comment: instead of changing the binding if i modify the html to reversename="reverseNameFn(message)" it works.

Comment: Yes, but only with the message parameter you pass to it. If you want to add other ones, you'll have to change the HTML.